# Need to load JSON sting into DataFrame

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON string that looks like this:

```
b'[{"status_verify":"0","dejatime_firstpaint":"0","fullip":"104.25.229.34","ctl_devlog":"69-131041194","resptime_fullpage":"0","dt_status":"2018-11-25 00:00:21","notified":"0","resptime_connect":"0.08799999952316284","http_resp_length":"0","resptime_firstbyte":"0.6819999814033508","obj_location":"31","max_fullpage_status":"-1","resptime_dns":"0","dejatime_pageload":"0","status":"0","resptime_redirect":"0","capture_exists":"0","resptime_content":"0.08799999952316284","rs_has_dejatime":"0","obj_cust":"117396","obj_device":"470630","childnodes":"0","deja_branched":"0","http_status":"HTTP 200 OK","info_msg":null,"device_descrip":"Get Public Datasets","dejatime_domload":"0","user_experience":"0","location_descrip":"San Francisco, California","dejatime_afttime":"0","resptime":"0.8579999804496765","obj_devlog":"152050515","test_cnt":"0","status_warning":"0"},{"status_verify":"0"

etc, etc, etc.
```

I am trying to pick out a few fields, and load these into a Data Frame, or just load everything into a Data Frame.  The problem is, these are all nested, and I don't know how to get actual field names from this massive string.

I tried this:

```
loaded_json = json.loads(json_data)
for x in loaded_json:
    print("%s: %d" % (x, loaded_json[x]))
```

And got this result: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict`.  I'm guessing this should be pretty straightforward, but I'm not sure how to proceed, even after Googling for a while for a solution.

Comment: thats because your root element is a `list` not `dict`, what exactly do you want to read from your JSON string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one line to load the data and then just put some fields in the DataFrame should be this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(x), columns=['status_verify', 'fullip', 'ctl_devlog'])
```

Good luck on your projects!

Answer (score 1):

That's because your top element is a list, you need to read from list not from `dict`,

```
import json

x = b'[{"status_verify":"0","dejatime_firstpaint":"0","fullip":"104.25.229.34","ctl_devlog":"69-131041194","resptime_fullpage":"0","dt_status":"2018-11-25 00:00:21","notified":"0","resptime_connect":"0.08799999952316284","http_resp_length":"0","resptime_firstbyte":"0.6819999814033508","obj_location":"31","max_fullpage_status":"-1","resptime_dns":"0","dejatime_pageload":"0","status":"0","resptime_redirect":"0","capture_exists":"0","resptime_content":"0.08799999952316284","rs_has_dejatime":"0","obj_cust":"117396","obj_device":"470630","childnodes":"0","deja_branched":"0","http_status":"HTTP 200 OK","info_msg":null,"device_descrip":"Get Public Datasets","dejatime_domload":"0","user_experience":"0","location_descrip":"San Francisco, California","dejatime_afttime":"0","resptime":"0.8579999804496765","obj_devlog":"152050515","test_cnt":"0","status_warning":"0"}]'


y = json.loads(x)
print(y[0]['status_verify'])

# output,
0
```

Comment: Thanks Sufiyan Ghori!!  I think this will do.  I just changed my code to this:
y = json.loads(json_data)
for p in y: 
    print(p['status_verify'])
    print(p['fullip'])
    print(p['ctl_devlog'])

Comment: Is there a best practice for loading these 3 items from the list into a Data Frame?